# C# Regex: Get all matches w/ name?

Tags: c#, regex

I've written a regex...

```
    internal static readonly Regex _parseSelector = new Regex(@"
        (?<tag>"+_validName+@")?
        (?:\.(?<class>"+_validName+ @"))*
        (?:\#(?<id>"+_validName+ @"))*
        (?<attr>\[
        \])*
        (?:\:(?<pseudo>.+?))*
    ", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

Now I want to get all the "class" bits...

```
var m = _parseSelector.Match("tag.class1.class2#id[]:pseudo");
```

How do to retrieve the list `class1, class2` from the match object?

Comment: @Oded: No... does that look like HTML? You're jumping the gun a bit ;)

Comment: fair enough... comment rescinded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach (var c in m.Groups["class"].Captures)
{
    Console.WriteLine(c);
}
```

Hurray for guessing.

Answer (score 1):

```
m.Groups["class"]
```

Comment: Yeah.. see, that part I knew, but `.Value` only returns the last match it seems. It's `.Captures` that I was looking for.